# How to find equation for $\theta_\lambda$

Tags: calculus, probability, machine-learning, estimation, least-squares

Suppose we have data $D=\{x_i,y_i\}_{i=1}^n$ where $x=(x_{i,1},x_{i,2},1)^T \in \mathbb{R}^3$. An estimator for these data,  $$y=f(x;\theta)=(\theta_1 x_1+\theta_2 x_2+\theta_3) ~~~(\theta \in \mathbb{R}^3)$$

To estimate the parameter $\theta$, squared error
$$L(\theta,\lambda)=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^n (y_i-f(x_i;\theta))^2+\frac{\lambda}{2}\theta^T\theta ~~~(\lambda ≥0)$$
My question is what is the equation that the parameter of estimated value $\theta_{\lambda}$ should satisfy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Differentiating the above equation wrt $\theta$ and setting it to zero,

For $p = 1,2,3$ we have

$\sum_{i=1}^n (y_i- f(x_i;\theta)) x_{ip} + \lambda \theta_p = 0 $

Using these three equations, get the values of $\theta_{1,2,3}$ in terms of $\lambda$